# Typekit fonts CSS not loading after ng build in Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, typekit, ng-build

I have imported the type-kit fonts css to my sass, its working fine on the local but when I run ng build for creating dist and upload on server, its started giving 403 error on type-kit. Any suggestions why its happening on server ?

Comment: Could you add to your question : the import code and a print screen of the network tab of browser.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

Go to the typekit website and setup your domain for all URL paths:

*.example.com

I have SASS compiled into CSS for my angular site and this did not work to import. So i added it to the index.html.

Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/yob1dgw.css">
```

The `index.html` is located directly under the `src` folder.

Then run your your `ng build --prod` and it should compile your `dist` folder and allow the typekit to be found.